# XPath Node selection

Tags: parsing, windows-phone-8, xpath, html-agility-pack, nodes

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse data for a Windows Phone 8 app. I have managed four nodes but I am having difficulties on the final one.

```
Game newGame = new Game();
newGame.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//section//h3").InnerText.Trim();
newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//section//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
newGame.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//section//p").InnerText.Trim();
newGame.StoreLink = div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[@class= 'Store']").Attributes["src"].Value;
newGame.Logo = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class= 'text-col'").FirstChild.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

That last piece of code is the one I am having problems with.  The HTML on the website looks like this (simplified with the data I need)

```
<div id= "ContentBlockList" class="tier ">
   <section>
      <div class="left-side"><img src="newGame.Cover"></div>
      <div class="text-col">
         <img src="newGame.Logo http://url.png" />
         <h3>newGame.Title</h3>
         <p>new.Game.Summary</p>
         <a href="https://link to online store"><img src="newGame.StoreLink" class="Store" /></a>
      </div>
</div>
</section>
```

As you can see, I need to parse two images from this block of HTML.  This code seems to take the first img src and uses it correctly for the game cover...

```
newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//section//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the second img src to retrieve the store Logo. Any ideas?

Comment: You can format HTML snippet using [online tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) as I did. Now we can clearly see that `section` opening and closing tag are not inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//img[2]").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

You didn't post the entire thing but, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I had the following error : An exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.XPath.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: '.img[2]' has an invalid token.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode("(.//img)[2]")
                   .GetAttributeValue("src", "");
```

`GetAttributeValue()` is preferable over `Attributes["..."].Value` because, while the latter throws exception, the former approach returns the 2nd parameter (empty string in the example above) when the attribute is not found.

Side note : your HTML markup is invalid as posted (some elements are not closed, `<section>` for example). That may cause confusion.

Comment: newGame.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode("(.//img)[2]").Attributes["src"].Value;